# curl: "Certificate key usage inadequate for attempted operation"

Tags: ssl, curl, certificate, self-signed

I've read quite a few posts regarding inadequate key usage and I think I understood how to make curl accept self-signed certificates, but I still can't make it work for me:

I have a trust store that contains the CA of my certificate:

```
./my.trust.crt
```

I retrieved the cert ./my.server.com.pem from the server using

```
> openssl s_client -showcerts -servername my.server.com -connect my.server.com:443
```

I checked that the certificate is fit for use:

```
> openssl verify -purpose sslserver -CAfile ./my.trust.crt my.server.com.pem
my.server.com.pem: OK
>
```

But still, curl complains:

```
> curl -v --cacert ./my.trust.crt https://my.server.com
* About to connect() to my.server.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.x.y...
* Connected to my.server.com (192.168.x.y) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: ./my.trust.crt
  CApath: none
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=my.server.com,OU=x,O=y,L=z,ST=ZH,C=CH
*       start date: Mar 07 13:19:00 2019 GMT
*       expire date: Mar 07 13:19:00 2029 GMT
*       common name:my.server.com
*       issuer: CN=My Certificate Authority,O=y,L=z,ST=ZH,C=CH
* NSS error -8102 (SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE)
* Certificate key usage inadequate for attempted operation.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) Certificate key usage inadequate for attempted operation.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
...
```

Any hints on how I could in find out what the problem is? Is my openssl verification correct? Anything else I'm doing wrong?

Additional info: there is a single CA in the ca "bundle". Anonymized contents of both CA and server certs as per suggestion (thanks!)

```
> openssl x509 -in my.server.pem -noout -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            c2:48:fb:ed:52:57:1e:24
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=CH, ST=ZH, L=Z, O=Company, CN=Company Certificate Authority
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar  7 13:19:00 2019 GMT
            Not After : Mar  7 13:19:00 2024 GMT
        Subject: C=CH, ST=ZH, L=Z, O=Company, OU=Dept, CN=my.server.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    <lots of hex stuff>
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                A4:51:53:0C:51:01:2F:51:48:D1:C0:49:B3:8B:CF:BD:7B:91:27:40
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:91:E5:80:D7:86:77:4C:B8:16:19:49:DF:74:E4:A7:05:D2:86:12:FE
                DirName:/C=CH/ST=ZH/L=Z/O=Company/CN=Company Certificate Authority
                serial:C2:48:FB:ED:52:57:1D:8B

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: critical
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:my.server.com, DNS:my-1.server.com, DNS:my-2.server.com
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         <lots of hex stuff>
         
> openssl x509 -in my.trust.crt -noout -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            c2:48:fb:ed:52:57:1d:8b
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=CH, ST=ZH, L=Z, O=Company, CN=Company Certificate Authority
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep  9 11:49:46 2015 GMT
            Not After : Sep  9 11:49:46 2025 GMT
        Subject: C=CH, ST=ZH, L=Z, O=Company, CN=Company Certificate Authority
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    <lots of hex stuff>
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                91:E5:80:D7:86:77:4C:B8:16:19:49:DF:74:E4:A7:05:D2:86:12:FE
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:91:E5:80:D7:86:77:4C:B8:16:19:49:DF:74:E4:A7:05:D2:86:12:FE

            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         <lots of hex stuff>
No Trusted Uses.
No Rejected Uses.
Alias: Company Certificate Authority
```

Comment: *"Anything else I'm doing wrong?"* - how should we know. You only provide information about the certificate which you found relevant and which don't show any problems. It is not even clear if the problem is caused by the leaf certificate which you checked or by the issuer certificate. Please provide full details for the complete chain, i.e. leaf certificate, issuer and potential intermediate certificates.

Comment: Doesn't
openssl "verify -purpose sslserver -CAfile ./my.trust.crt my.server.com.pem
my.server.com.pem: OK"
show that the the combination of ca and cert add up?

Comment: There can be other reasons. For example having the same subject for leaf certificate and CA might mess up the finding of the proper issuer which can cause such issues too. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1590217

Comment: There is exactly one CA certificcate in my.trust.crt (the issuer of my.server.com.pem) and its subject matches the issuer from my.server.com.pem. Both subjects very different... Sorry for being so secretive. Can't post the two certificates, cause I need permission to do so (yeah, I know should be harmless, but then, I'm not my CISO :-)...)
Any flag or keytool /openssl x509 command I could invoke to get more clarity on why this thing doesn't work? (Note that we've got hundrets of certs issued with this CA, no problem with any other TLS web server communication, just curl doesn't like it.)

Comment: Can you provide the output of `openssl x509 -text -noout` but anonymize the subject and issuer (same input, same output for anonymization) and remove the details of the public key? Maybe one could regenerate certificates based on this to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for providing the certificates. What I see is that the leaf certificate has no key usage of keyEncipherment, which would be required if the server wants to use RSA key exchange. So it would be interesting to do a packet capture of the TLS handshake and see which cipher the server proposes. Wireshark is a useful tool for such analysis.

Comment: Thanks bunches @SteffenUllrich for taking the time to look at it. I'll investigate and get back (but might take a day or two...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SteffenUllrich correctly pointed out: the keyEncipherment usage was missing in the server certificate. Adding this (respectively creating certificates that include this usage) solved the issue!